# domainlists in exim config dkim_verify_signers

Tags: exim

I have the following in the main section of my exim4 config:

```
domainlist require_dkim_signed_mail_domains = gmail.com:paypal.com
dkim_verify_signers = $dkim_signers : +require_dkim_signed_mail_domains
```

`$dkim_signers` is a list generated on receiving an email of domains found in `DKIM-Signature` headers.

What I thought that would do is call the DKIM ACL for all DKIM signatures found, and definitely call it for gmail and paypal, since these senders are known to always sign mail.

However, the `+require_dkim_signed_mail_domains` is not being expanded; instead it's getting processed as a string.

Why? And how can I use a variable to store a list of domains (and therefore save trouble of maintaining the same list in multiple places)?